# +5 за голос «за» на ответе

Tags: поддержка, репутация, голоса-за

Кто мне объяснит, как голос "за" за мой ответ дал всего +5 репутации, а не +10?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578485/221228

Comment: Как-то связано с дневным ограничением репы? Только непонятно, почему не последний голос обрезался.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это связано с дневным ограничением репутации: у вас просто получилось до этого голоса 195 репутации, полученной с помощью голосов "за". Репутация получилась кратной пяти, так как у вас ещё есть +15 на момент написания (3 голоса "за" ваш [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/805072/220571)). Поскольку есть дневной лимит, то репутация за этого голос обрезалась.

Я видел подобные примеры, когда, к примеру, у участника за голос "за" в репутации было +2: просто у участника было очень много голосов "за" и единственный голос "против".

Вот скриншот вашей репутации для наглядности:

[image]

Comment: Что такое "дневной лимит", в свете того факта, что за сегодня я набрал +292? Или это лучше отдельным вопросом оформить?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Не надо отдельных вопросов. Вам приведут [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) или посты вроде [этого](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/346987). Там всё есть. Цитата из справки: "В день можно заработать до 200 баллов репутации любым сочетанием приведенных ниже действий. Конкурсы, принятые ответы и бонусы за подключения к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов не ограничены дневным пределом репутации.". Ваш случай: +200 голоса за ваши вопросы/ответы (это максимум), +90 за принятые ответы другими участниками, +2 за принятый вами ответ.

Comment: "Принятые ответы" это принятый мной ответы или мои ответы, принятые автором вопроса?

Comment: Все. Разобрался. Спасибо

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, твои ответы, принятые автором вопроса, если это не ты сам. Только за такие дают +15. За принятие чужого ответа на свой вопрос дают +2, но я не помню, входят ли они в лимит. За принятие своего ответа на свой вопрос не дают ничего.